# Sublime Text 3 - new files not opening on new tabs?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I just installed sublime 3. But I can't open new files in new tabs anymore.

The new files just keep replacing the current one. I have this setting in mine:

```
{
    "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "caret_style": "phase",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/iPlastic.tmTheme",
    "default_line_ending": "unix",
    "draw_white_space": "all",
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
    "font_size": 11,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "highlight_modified_tabs": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "rulers":
    [
        120
    ],
    "scroll_past_end": true,
    "show_full_path": true,
    "spell_check": true,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
    "word_wrap": true
}
```

What have I missed?

This is the copy I get from its site:

```
sublime-text_build-3126_amd64.deb
```

Comment: what are you doing to open files? using the sidebar? maybe set `"preview_on_click": false,`

Comment: @KeithHall have tried to set that but still no luck.

Comment: Does it also occur when double-clicking a file or after changing a file?

Comment: @idleberg I turned off the tab from `view` by mistake. now works. thanks.